# iOS7 How to take OpenGLES screenshot.

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm using VLCKit to play video in my app, and I need to be able to take a screenshot of the video at certain points. This is the code I'm using:

```
-(NSData*)generateThumbnail{


    int s = 1;
    UIScreen* screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    if ([screen respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        s = (int) [screen scale];
    }

    GLint viewport[4];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);


    int width = viewport[2];
    int height = [_profile.resolution integerValue];//viewport[3];

    int myDataLength = width * height * 4;
    GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
    GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    for(int y1 = 0; y1 < height; y1++) {
        for(int x1 = 0; x1 <width * 4; x1++) {
            buffer2[(height - 1 - y1) * width * 4 + x1] = buffer[y1 * 4 * width + x1];
        }
    }
    free(buffer);

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, myDataLength, NULL);
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * width;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    UIImage *image = [ UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:s orientation:UIImageOrientationUp ];
     NSData *thumbAsData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 5);
    return thumbAsData;

}
```

To be honest, I have no idea how most of this works. I copied it from somewhere a while ago (I don't remember the source). It *mostly* works, however frequently it seems parts of the image are missing.

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

Can someone point me in the right direction? Most of the other posts I see regarding OpenGL screenshots are fairly old, and don't seem to apply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok turns out this is a problem only in the Simulator. On a device it seems to work 98% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a class to work around this problem.

Basically you take directly a **screenshot from the screen**, and then if you want you can take just a part of the image and also scale it.

Taking a screenshot from the screen, you take every stuff. UIKit , OpenGL, AVFoundation, etc.

Here the class: https://github.com/matteogobbi/MGScreenshotHelper/

Below useful functions, but i suggest you to download (and star :D) directly my helper class ;)

```
/* Get the screenshot of the screen (useful when you have UIKit elements and OpenGL or AVFoundation stuff */
+ (UIImage *)screenshotFromScreen
{
    CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage(void);
    CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
    UIImage* screenImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
    CGImageRelease(screen);

    return screenImage;
}

/* Get the screenshot of a determinate rect of the screen, and scale it to the size that you want. */
+ (UIImage *)getScreenshotFromScreenWithRect:(CGRect)captureRect andScaleToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIImage *image = [[self class] screenshotFromScreen];
    image = [[self class] cropImage:image withRect:captureRect];
    image = [[self class] scaleImage:image toSize:newSize];

    return image;
}


#pragma mark - Other methods

/* Get a portion of an image */
+ (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)image withRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *cropedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    return cropedImage;
}

/* Scale an image */
+ (UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return scaledImage;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... seems to work but with some caveats. Firstly it also captures the video-control GUI I have layer over the video, and also if I have the device in landscape mode, the image is 90 degrees off. I'm going to take these issues to your github page.

Comment: Also if I use `+ (UIImage *)getScreenshotFromView:(UIView *)captureView` to pass in the OpenGL view's container view. I get a black screen, which I guess is the same thing everyone is having trouble with.

Comment: You must not use that fiction. That function is just for uikit. There is written also in the comment. For this reason I post the function getScreenshotFromScreen that take all the stuff. And there is also the function to take the photo, crop a part and scale it. So you haven't problem. If you want rotate the photo it is easy you find a lot of function to integrate the class.